# where does openvswitch handle the TCP seq and ack?

Tags: sdn, openflow, openvswitch

I use multiple actions in flow table using openvswitch. When I want to modify TCP ipv4_dst and copy the packet to the other outport, the ack number of the packet is changed randomly. And I do not change other fields in IP header. Why does this happen? I don't want to see the change of ack number.

the flow table items :
OFPST_FLOW reply (OF1.3) (xid=0x2):
 cookie=0x0, duration=6.846s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=6,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.2,nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:1

cookie=0x0, duration=6.846s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=7,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.2 actions=output:2,set_field:10.0.0.3->ip_dst,set_field:00:00:00:00:00:03->eth_dst,output:3

cookie=0x0, duration=6.846s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=8,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.3,nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:1

cookie=0x0, duration=6.847s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535

the topology:
10.0.0.1--------switch--------10.0.0.2
                  |
                  |
               10.0.0.3

[image]

Comment: Only the [destination IP and checksums should change](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/457402dc2aaa2a73e5a3142962d4a091379170cc/datapath/actions.c#L415-L422). Can you show the content of your flow table?

Comment: I add the flow table above. And I have test it in some different scenario.I found that when I output to port 2, change the destination IP and output to port 3, the ack number will be changed. But when I output to port2, change the destination mac address and output to port3, the ack number will be correct. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing your setup with Mininet, I am unable to reproduce the issue.

1. [Open vSwitch's code to change IP addresses is pretty straightforward](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/457402dc2aaa2a73e5a3142962d4a091379170cc/datapath/actions.c#L415-L422). There is no mention of sequence numbers.
2. I used `ovs-appctl ofproto/trace` to trace Open vSwitch's behavior when receiving a TCP packet:

   ```
   ovs-appctl ofproto/trace s1 in_port=1,dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:01,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:02,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.2
   ```

   The output doesn't include any sequence number modification.
3. I compared packets on ports 2 and 3 using Wireshark. They have the exact same ACK numbers in my case.

These three points lead me to believe that your problem doesn't come from Open vSwitch. Could the ACK number modification come from some other piece of software? Are you running your experiments in Mininet or on physical hosts?

Comment: grateful to see your answer. I also repeated my expriment today. I run the expriment in Mininet. I printk the ack number in /var/log/syslog, and I found that :the ack number dose not be changed with the function as you mentioned.But the ack number showed in wireshark is changed.(I will show the picture above.) And what makes me confused is that: if I change the packet's dst_IP and out_port, the ack number will be changed in wireshark, but if I change the dst_IP and do not change out_port, the ack number will not be changed in wireshark.

Comment: TCP flow :host1 to host2.
1:inport=1,actions:output_port:to host2,set_field(dst_IP=host3,dst_mac=host3), output_port:to host3.  (The ack number showed in output_port to host3 is changed to random number.)
2:inport=1,actions:output_port:to host2,set_field(dst_IP=host3,dst_mac=host3), output_port:to host2. (The ack number is normal.)
It is so strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
Because of the monitoring of tcp connection in Linux kernel, we cannot copy the tcp state.

Comment: Could you explain further how that changes the ACK number?

Comment: I am sorry that I make the wrong answer. The fact is that when we copy the TCP packet, the seq in  packet ACK coming from the receivers is different, because the initial seq is randomly generated by host. However, the following copy of TCP packet is based on the first TCP connection, and so it cannot guarantee the correctness of ACK number for all TCP connection.